# What can cause a sudden crash of a laptop on battery power?

Tags: laptop, crash, battery

HP Pavilion DM3 / Windows 7
My laptop suddenly goes black without warning, restart and it goes to "Start Windows Normally."

Does not occur when plugged in to AC.

I got a new battery and had similar, if not more frequent events, after a few days.

Could be hardware related to the discharge circuitry or possibly both batteries drift down and suddenly kill the machine.

Any thoughts re: cause or ways to evaluate the problem. The crash is so sudden, it is unlikely an identifiable log even is generated.

Comment: definitely sounds like a hardware issue on the laptop.  is it still under warranty?

Comment: Could you boot into a Linux live CD and see whether the problem occurs there also? Does windows report the battery as fully charged? Have you checked the windows events logs?

Answer (score 1):

It is either the hardware or battery that is causing the problem. Possibly the loose connection problem at the junction where the battery is supplying power to the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a hardware error in something else than the battery because the problem persists after a battery change.

I would like you to try the computer with Linux so that you can rule out a software error, also this might make it easier to see if it for example  always dies at a specific charge  percentage.