# What hardware faults could cause random crashing on battery only in a Dell XPS 12 9Q23 laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dell-xps

I am having the exact same fault as this chap:
[What can cause a sudden crash of a laptop on battery power?](https://superuser.com/questions/538667/what-can-cause-a-sudden-crash-of-a-laptop-on-battery-power)

Summary of the problem: My laptop randomly crashes while on battery power (not AC). Typically crashes around 70% but can be random. Goes completely dead (black screen) and reboots itself. When it gets to the Windows loading it crashes again and enters a cycle of rebooting and crashing. Only plugging it in stops the issue.

I have changed the battery twice and the issue persists. I have also dual booted linux and also crashed on this, so I know it's a non-battery hardware fault.

Any thoughts on what it could be causing this? Laptop model is a Dell XPS 12 9Q23. Really frustrating but would rather not bin the laptop if can be avoided.

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Get it checked by a service technician.

Comment: I'm really looking to understand whether there are any obvious hardware issues that could cause this. It's not really worth taking it to a technician given how old the laptop is and how much this would cost. I'd sooner attempt to change a piece of hardware that could be suspect if possible, else just use it on power until I change.

Comment: At a total guess, power circuity in the laptop - maybe a capacitor? Its unlikely this can trivially be fixed.

Comment: Thanks David,I suspect you may be right. What's getting me is the fact that it'll work for a period of time - sometimes up to an hour - before crashing. Could this still fit the bill for being a dodgy capacitor?